# Disallow access and bot indexing in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, noindex

A htaccess protected subdirectory of my website somehow has been indexed (months ago) by google. I had to add this directory to robots.txt but I don't want the protected url to be visible in robots.txt anymore.
I switched this directory to a new name and it won't probably be indexed again as it's not referenced anywhere but... just in case, I would like to add a noindex to it.

I added to my subdirectory .htaccess

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
```

It's working fine when I disable htaccess protection (I get the noindex header response). As soon as I add the protection

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpassword
Require user admin
```

and simulate an error by hitting cancel on the authentication window, I get a 401 error and no "noindex" header.

Should I find a way to add a noindex on the 401 error page or is there an other way to manage that?

Comment: I think the `noindex` header on the `401` response is not necessary, because in general the crawler will not attempt to do anymore crawling after receiving a `401` response. But i am not 100% sure, anyway [here](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/admin_console_help/crawl_access.html) is some information about how google crawler handles authenticated content crawling.

Comment: that's also what I thought, can't explain why it has indexed it once...